# How to set python package search paths in VSCode for jupyter/jupytex?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

My project file structures:

```
MyProject/
    |- src/
        packageA/
            |- __init__.py
            |- moduleA.py
    |- Playground/
        |- foo.py
        |- bar/
            |- baz.py
```

In `Playground/foo.py` and `Playground/bar/baz.py`, I write some python code which can be treated as JupyterNotebook cells with [`#%%`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python#_jupyter-notebooks):

```py
# Playground/foo.py & Playground/bar/baz.py

# %% I can run this cell with IPython in VSCode by shift+enter
import sys
print(sys.path)

import packageA
```

After running the cells by `shift + enter`, they show:

```
['{path_to_vscode_workspace}/Playground', ...]

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'packageA'
```

The paths do not contain the `{path_to_vscode_workspace}` but the working directory of `foo.py` (`{path_to_vscode_workspace}/Playground`).

How to set the python package search paths in `settings.json` with VSCode specific parameters?

- using setup in `settings.json` without adding code in any `.py` file.
- using relative search paths to keep working on another computer (different workspace path)

Answer (score 0):

If you run the following code in `foo.py`, you'll find the current working directory(**cwd**) is `..\MyProject\Playground`. Of course there's no module called packageA in current folder:

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

Before the import sentence, add the following code both in `foo.py` and `baz.py`, which is changing cwd to MyProject:

```
import os
os.chdir("the absolute path to MyProject")
```

Then you can `import src.PackageA` successfully:

[image]

**[Update]**

Add the following configuration in launch.json and **Run without Debugging**

```
"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
"env": {
    "PYTHONPATH":"${workspaceFolder}"
}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, I know that. I'm looking for a solution to add a **relative search path to current workspace** in global **settings.json** without adding code in any .py file or any repository.

Comment: Ok, I've found another workaround if you don't insist on using jupyter cells in .py file, you can edit the launch configuration. please check my update.